How to get the complete path with CTE
I have a table like below:



ID
NextID




1
5


2
NULL


3
6


4
7


5
8


6
9


7
NULL


8
NULL


9
10


10
NULL



I want to get the ID path:
1 --> 5 --> 8
2
3 --> 6 --> 9 --> 10
4 --> 7

and I tried this:
WITH RECURSIVE path_cte AS (
  SELECT ID, NextID, ID::TEXT AS Path
  FROM t1
  WHERE NextID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.NextID, t1.ID || ' --> ' || cte.Path
  FROM t1
  JOIN path_cte cte ON t1.NextID = cte.ID
)
SELECT Path
FROM path_cte
ORDER BY ID;

but I got the output:
1 --> 5 --> 8
2
3 --> 6 --> 9 --> 10
4 --> 7
5 --> 8
6 --> 9 --> 10
7
8
9 --> 10
10

I don't want to get those incomplete paths, but I don't know how to achieve that.
The path is based on ID and NextID, if NextID is NULL, the path ends, and this ID is the end of the path, the next is to trace forward to get a complete path.
If an ID has neither a preceding ID nor a subsequent ID, it is also considered a path.
The database I use is compatible with PostgreSQL syntax, so you can also use PostgreSQL to demo, thanks :)

@lucky Thanks for improving your question. I have just one question left: Can you have another row with ID 11 and next id 6 in your table or are both columns unique? If it is possible you have such a row, should the result then contain the path 11 --> 6 --> 9 --> 10?

@JonasMetzler Such data will not appear in the table. Every ID has at most one preceding ID and one subsequent ID.

@Zegarek, thank you for test model

@ValNik you're welcome but if you wanted to share something, the fiddle you pasted under "model" is a blank one.

It's a pity that it happened that way. Anyway, thank you very much.

If you don't mind, I'll migrate your testing model and add my own query test examples

@ValNik Sure, go ahead. I was using db-fiddle.com only because PostgreSQL instances at dbfiddle.uk were temporarily down today. Be sure to update your answer because the links there lead to empty fiddles too.

If you can afford a versatile, battle-tested, highly optimised (Boost C++ level of optimised) extension which pgrouting is, what I'd also consider is not trying to solve a long-solved problem. Your data set can be interpreted as a graph, and that's what this extension does: graphs.
The problem you're dealing with two calls. One pgr_connectedComponents():

A connected component of an undirected graph is a set of vertices that are all reachable from each other.

alter table t1 add column subgraph integer;

explain analyze verbose
update t1 set subgraph=c.component
from pgr_connectedComponents(
  $x$ select row_number()over() as id
           , coalesce(id,nextid,1e7::int) as source
           , coalesce(nextid,id,1e7::int) as target
           , 1      as cost
           , 1      as reverse_cost
      from t1 
  $x$) as c
where c.node=t1.id;--4087.475 ms

create index on t1(subgraph,id,nextid)with(fillfactor=100);

That establishes individual subgraphs/trees/chains/disjoined groups of nodes. Once you have that, you can run any routing or spanning tree algorithm you want. E.g. pgr_dijkstra():
select string_agg(node::text,' --> ' order by path_seq) as path
from(select subgraph
          , id as bottom
          , (select id from t1 as t2 
             where t1.subgraph=t2.subgraph
             and t2.nextid is null) as top
     from t1 
     where id is not null 
       and not exists(select from t1 as t2 
                      where t2.nextid=t1.id)) as top_bottom_per_subgraph
cross join lateral pgr_dijkstra(
      format($x$ select row_number()over() as id
                   , coalesce(id,nextid,2e9::int) as source
                   , coalesce(nextid,id,2e9::int) as target
                   , 1 as cost
                   , 1 as reverse_cost
              from t1
              where id is not null
                and subgraph=%L 
             $x$, top_bottom_per_subgraph.subgraph)
    ,top_bottom_per_subgraph.bottom
    ,top_bottom_per_subgraph.top)
group by subgraph;--4058.037 ms

It does a single run between the top and bottom nodes in each subgraph. In each case you tell pgrouting what you want and leave worrying how to do that efficiently to decades of C++ freaks.
On 1'000'000 randomised rows with the longest chain/largest group of 100k, the first part takes 4087ms, the second 4058ms.
db<>fiddle, db-fiddle and sqlfiddle don't offer pgrouting, which is why I couldn't attach an online demo but when I run the answers posted here so far on the same env, these are the results:



variant
score




pgr_topologicalSort on a DAG
3'546ms


Dijkstra on subgraphs (this)
8'145ms


ValNik
44'912ms


hobgoblin
182'969 ms


Patrick Chin
210'174 ms


Jonas Metzler
timed out after 12h




By "afford" I mean in terms of time or political capital - pgrouting is free and open-source.

This can be solved by augmenting the query with FirstID and Lvl. Then select distinct FirstID sorted by the longest path length (Lvl).
demo at db<>fiddle
WITH RECURSIVE path_cte AS (
  SELECT ID
       , ID::text AS Path
       , ID AS FirstID
       , 1 as Lvl
  FROM t1
  WHERE NextID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.ID
       , t1.ID::text ||' --> '|| cte.Path
       , cte.FirstId
       , cte.Lvl + 1
  FROM t1
  JOIN path_cte cte 
    ON t1.NextID = cte.ID
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (FirstID) Path
FROM path_cte
ORDER BY FirstID, Lvl Desc, ID;


On 2k random samples, this is significantly faster (11ms down from 5400ms) and also more correct. For some reason the other solution fails to catch 3 groups (2, 4 --> 7, 16 --> 18): demo.

@Zegarek Thank you for your very detailed testing.

Recursive sampling is best started from the end vertices, where nextid is null. Let's call this node an anchor.
To select the correct rows for output, you need to take the longest path for each source anchor as
row_number()over(partition by anchor order by lvl desc)
See example
with recursive r as(
      SELECT 0 lvl,pid,pid anchor
         ,cast(pid as varchar(100))path
      from test t
      where nextid is null -- not exists(select pid from test t2 where t2.pid=t.nextid)
      union all
      SELECT lvl+1,t.pid,r.anchor
         ,cast(concat(t.pid,'-->',r.path) as varchar(100)) path
      from r inner join test t on t.nextid=r.pid
     )
select pid,path  ,lvl,anchor,rn
from(
     SELECT * 
       ,row_number()over(partition by anchor order by lvl desc)rn
     from r
  )a
where rn=1;




pid
path
lvl
anchor
rn




1
1-->5-->8
2
8
1


2
2
0
2
1


3
3-->6-->9-->10
3
10
1


4
4-->7
1
7
1



We can start recursion from start vertices. The anchor part of the recursion will be somewhat heavier.   Perhaps, condition where r.nextid is not null in recursion part slightly improve the recursion.
There target rows from recursion query - where nextid is null:
with recursive r as(
      SELECT 0 lvl,pid,nextid
         ,cast(pid as varchar(100))path
      from test t
      where not exists(select pid from test t2 where t.pid=t2.nextid)
      union all
      SELECT lvl+1,r.pid,t.nextid
         ,cast(concat(r.path,'-->',t.pid) as varchar(100)) path
      from r inner join test t on r.nextid=t.pid
      where r.nextid is not null
 )
select pid,path  ,lvl,nextid 
from r
where nextid is null;




pid
path
lvl
nextid




1
1-->5-->8
2
null


2
2
0
null


3
3-->6-->9-->10
3
null


4
4-->7
1
null



Update1.  I tried these queries above in a test data model made by @Zegarek. Special thanks to him for the opportunity to test and review the execution plans. Model and tests
Update2. Data samples and test from @Zegarek, teemed to me very interesting and instructive.
As commented, Thats mainly thanks to an easier escape and filtering the complete chains found by the CTE.
The second significant difference between first query option (as well as the option from @PatrickChan) and my second option is the need to sort the entire output stream of a recursive query to take first (rn=1) or distinct path. This is an expensive operation. And, I think, it is the sorting that causes the event of a lack of disk space and a timeout in execution.

The second option is great. Heavier anchor more than justifies the 2x gains on 100k(had to discard the first example in the demo because it times out way before that). Thats mainly thanks to an easier escape and filtering the complete chains found by the CTE. It's also the only one that survives a 5500-element chain, the others running out of space.

Based on your explanation that both columns are unique, meaning another row like for  example ID 11 and NextID 6 is not possible, you want to exclude all paths that are part of another part. This can be done using a NOT EXISTS subquery:
WITH RECURSIVE path_cte AS (
  SELECT ID, NextID, ID::TEXT AS Path
  FROM t1
  WHERE NextID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.NextID, t1.ID || ' --> ' || cte.Path
  FROM t1
  JOIN path_cte cte ON t1.NextID = cte.ID
)
SELECT path
FROM path_cte p_main
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM path_cte p_sub 
   WHERE 
     p_main.id <> p_sub.id AND
     p_sub.path LIKE '%' || p_main.path || '%')
ORDER BY p_main.ID;

This produces following result:



path




1 --> 5 --> 8


2


3 --> 6 --> 9 --> 10


4 --> 7



See this db<>fiddle with your sample data.

Thanks for the question, it has a nice twist to it. Here is a recursive query which calculates the path for all roots, as arrays of nodes:
with recursive
t1(id,nextid) as (
  values (1,5), (2,null), (3,6), (4,7), (5,8), (6,9), (7,null), (8,null), (9,10), (10,null)
),
roots(id) as (
  select id from t1   except   select nextid from t1
),
initial_paths(path,last) as (
  select array[]::int[], id from roots
),
paths(path,id) as (
  select path, last from initial_paths
  union
  select array_append(path,id), nextid
  from   paths
  join   t1    using (id)
)
select path
from   paths
where  id is null




path




{2}


{4,7}


{1,5,8}


{3,6,9,10}



View on DB Fiddle
How does it work?
The first CTE is just the input data, table t1. The query named roots calculates all root nodes (all nodes which occur in column id of t1, but not in column nextid). Query initial_paths translates all root nodes into paths. The recursive query paths then extends all paths as much as possible.
The query has to perform several functions:

append the current node to the path (if the current node is not null)
generate the path as a result if it was extended
mark the paths which are final (the next node after the last is null)
calculate the next node

Step 2. must be done on the input side, so it is easiest to use the current node from the previous recursion (so we can suppress the result and the extending with the same condition). If the path is selected for the result because the current node is not null, the extended path can then be built with the current node, and in parallel the next node can be calculated (which will become the current node in the next recursion).
The obvious solution would generate paths like {2,null}, that is it would calculate and append a next node as long as possible, until the next node is null (and append that too).
Another solution would be to create a CTE which suppresses elements from t1 with nextid = null.

Your sample looks like it might be a directed acyclic graph. If that's the case it would enable it to use pgr_topologicalSort(), shorter and faster than regular Dijkstra on a graph allowing cycles:
with topologically_sorted as(
   select*,count(*)--increments at the end of each chain, establishing subgraphs
            filter(where sorted_v<0)
            over(order by seq)as subgraph
   from pgr_topologicalsort( 
   $x$ select row_number()over() as id
            , id as source
            , coalesce(nextid,-id) as target--negated `id` at each chain end
            , 1 as cost 
       from t1 
       where id is not null
   $x$)as g(seq,sorted_v))
select count(*) as subgraph_size
     , string_agg(sorted_v::text,' --> ' order by seq) as path
from topologically_sorted
where sorted_v>=0 --artificially added chain ends excluded
group by subgraph;--3546.448ms on a 1M sample




subgraph_size
path (sample, those are long)




3
1 --> 5 --> 8


1
2


4
3 --> 6 --> 9 --> 10


2
4 --> 7


5
13 --> 12 --> 14 --> 11 --> 15


2
16 --> 18


2
20 --> 19


99980
100000 --> 99999 --> 99998 --> 99997 --> 99996 --> 99995 --> 99994 --> 99993 --> ...


39
100152 --> 133395 --> 599751 --> 332137 --> 743392 --> 229349 --> 957179 --> ...


2
100282 --> 694717


54
100334 --> 173574 --> 551034 --> 208879 --> 532780 --> 189441 --> 898525 --> ...


130
100346 --> 695935 --> 391371 --> 456121 --> 479046 --> 368277 --> 201408 --> ...




WITH RECURSIVE path_cte AS (
    -- Start with paths that end at NULL (leaves)
    SELECT ID, NextID, ID::TEXT AS Path
    FROM t1
    WHERE NextID IS NULL
  
    UNION ALL

    -- Recursively build the paths
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.NextID, t1.NextID::TEXT || ' --> ' || cte.Path
    FROM t1
    JOIN path_cte cte ON t1.ID = cte.NextID
)
SELECT DISTINCT Path
FROM path_cte
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t1 t2
    WHERE t2.NextID = path_cte.ID  -- Check if there are children/next IDs
)
ORDER BY MIN(ID);  -- Order by the minimum ID in each path

I hope it can help you

Please explain how this solves the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

This query is incorrect and will produce an error message.

The WHERE NOT EXISTS clause in the final selection filters out paths where there are still entries in t1 that have the current ID as a NextID, which indicates that the current ID is not a leaf and thus should not be in the final result.
